# Creating a new column when reading the file in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an input file which looks as such:

```
input_range   1.020000
ascii_format  TRUE
data          5000
0.000000e+000   2.902222e-001
1.000000e+000   2.902222e-001
2.000000e+000   2.905273e-001
3.000000e+000   2.902222e-001
4.000000e+000   2.911377e-001
5.000000e+000   2.908325e-001
input_range   1.020000
ascii_format  TRUE
data          5000
0.000000e+000   3.902222e-001
1.000000e+000   3.902222e-001
2.000000e+000   3.905273e-001
3.000000e+000   3.902222e-001
4.000000e+000   3.911377e-001
5.000000e+000   3.908325e-001
```

I would like to have an output file which would contain 3 columns: first two columns after reading first 'data' string and only the second column (which will be the third in output file) after reading the second 'data' string. I do not know if I can do it only in data frames? Or with readlines command or rather combine both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a *regex* approach, then call [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)/[`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) :

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

with open("file.txt") as f:
    df = (
        pd.concat([
            pd.read_fwf(StringIO(bloc), header=None, index_col=0)
            for bloc in re.findall(r"data\s+\d+\n(.*?)(?=input|\Z)",
            f.read(), re.S)], axis=1).reset_index().pipe(lambda x:
            x.set_axis([f"c{i+1}" for i in range(len(x.columns))], axis=1))
         )
```

Output :

```
print(df)

    c1        c2        c3
0  0.0  0.290222  0.390222
1  1.0  0.290222  0.390222
2  2.0  0.290527  0.390527
3  3.0  0.290222  0.390222
4  4.0  0.291138  0.391138
5  5.0  0.290832  0.390833
```

Comment: I was trying to use the code for my file and it is not creating 3 columns... until I didn't specify the separator in my file but it works now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to get different columns for different data hunks, you'll have to go through the file yourself. But you can still take advantage of pandas to export to csv:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import re

input_f = StringIO(r"""input_range   1.020000
ascii_format  TRUE
data          5000
0.000000e+000   2.902222e-001
1.000000e+000   2.902222e-001
2.000000e+000   2.905273e-001
3.000000e+000   2.902222e-001
4.000000e+000   2.911377e-001
5.000000e+000   2.908325e-001
input_range   1.020000
ascii_format  TRUE
data          5000
0.000000e+000   3.902222e-001
1.000000e+000   3.902222e-001
2.000000e+000   3.905273e-001
3.000000e+000   3.902222e-001
4.000000e+000   3.911377e-001
5.000000e+000   3.908325e-001""")

data_array = []
get_data = False
data_hunk = 0

columns_to_get = {
    1: [0, 2],   # will get columns 0 (included) to 2 (not included) for the first data hunk
    2: [1, 2],   # will get columns 1 (included) to 2 (not included) for the second data hunk
}

col_range = []
df = pd.DataFrame()

for line in input_f:
    if line[0:4] == 'data':
        get_data = True
        data_hunk += 1
        col_range = columns_to_get[data_hunk]
        continue
    if line[0:11] == 'input_range':
        get_data = False
        df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(data_array)], axis=1)
        data_array = []
        continue
    if get_data:
        data_array.append(re.split(r'\s+', line)[col_range[0]:col_range[1]])

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(data_array)], axis=1)

df.to_csv('output.csv', header=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

`output.csv`:

```
,col1,col2,col3
0,0.000000e+000,2.902222e-001,3.902222e-001
1,1.000000e+000,2.902222e-001,3.902222e-001
2,2.000000e+000,2.905273e-001,3.905273e-001
3,3.000000e+000,2.902222e-001,3.902222e-001
4,4.000000e+000,2.911377e-001,3.911377e-001
5,5.000000e+000,2.908325e-001,3.908325e-001
```